# How to Detect if Multiple Nodes Exist in GraphStream

Tags: java, graph, graphstream

This is a pretty obscure question since I don't see many people fawning over GraphStream, but does anyone know how to detect if a node exists in the graph if it has been inserted?

For example, if I write

`graph.addNode(vertex1);`

I get an error. If I do the same thing and write

`graph.addNode(vertex1);`

This is because vertex1 already exists in the graph. I can't find anything in GraphStream's documentation [here](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/) and I can't find an answer anywhere I look. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in the [Documentation](https://data.graphstream-project.org/api/gs-core/current/org/graphstream/graph/Graph.html#addNode(java.lang.String)) :

> Throws: IdAlreadyInUseException - If strict checking is enabled the identifier
>   is already used.

You should be able to find out if an identifier is used by checking the returned value of  `getNode(vertex1.getId())`.

[getNode(String id)](https://data.graphstream-project.org/api/gs-core/current/org/graphstream/graph/Graph.html#getNode(java.lang.String)) :

> Returns: The searched node or null if not found.